# COPR fedoraproject.org builder refuses to download sources specified in my .spec file

Tags: fedora, rpmbuild, rpm-spec, copr

I have a package build in https://copr.fedoraproject.org. My [spec for rpkg is here](https://github.com/jiridanek/skupper-router/blob/c4e28b63ddfc950c1fe34a37bf38daf25f628b70/skupper-router.spec.rpkg). The build is failing with the following

```
Generated rpkg config:
[rpkg]
preprocess_spec = True

[git]
anon_clone_url = https://github.com/%(repo_path)s

[lookaside]
download_url = https://${git_props:remote_netloc}/repo/pkgs/%(repo_path)s/%(filename)s/%(hashtype)s/%(hash)s/%(filename)s

Writing config into /var/lib/copr-rpmbuild/workspace/workdir-ce16hwto/.config/rpkg.conf
Running: rpkg srpm --outdir /var/lib/copr-rpmbuild/results --spec /var/lib/copr-rpmbuild/workspace/workdir-ce16hwto/skupper-router

cmd: ['rpkg', 'srpm', '--outdir', '/var/lib/copr-rpmbuild/results', '--spec', '/var/lib/copr-rpmbuild/workspace/workdir-ce16hwto/skupper-router']
cwd: /var/lib/copr-rpmbuild/workspace/workdir-ce16hwto/skupper-router
rc: 1
stdout: Wrote: /var/lib/copr-rpmbuild/results/skupper-router.spec
stderr: git_dir_pack: archiving /var/lib/copr-rpmbuild/workspace/workdir-ce16hwto/skupper-router:
commit cb2a29004b1660168cc4a6894e521b0cf71cb25d (HEAD -> jd_2022_03_15_rpm, origin/jd_2022_03_15_rpm)
Date:   Sat Apr 9 01:04:32 2022 +0200

    add static build rpm
git_dir_pack: Wrote: /var/lib/copr-rpmbuild/results/skupper-router-cb2a2900.tar.gz
error: Bad source: /var/lib/copr-rpmbuild/results/qpid-proton-0.37.0.tar.gz: No such file or directory

Copr build error: git_dir_pack: archiving /var/lib/copr-rpmbuild/workspace/workdir-ce16hwto/skupper-router:
commit cb2a29004b1660168cc4a6894e521b0cf71cb25d (HEAD -> jd_2022_03_15_rpm, origin/jd_2022_03_15_rpm)
Date:   Sat Apr 9 01:04:32 2022 +0200

    add static build rpm
git_dir_pack: Wrote: /var/lib/copr-rpmbuild/results/skupper-router-cb2a2900.tar.gz
error: Bad source: /var/lib/copr-rpmbuild/results/qpid-proton-0.37.0.tar.gz: No such file or directory
```

(full log at https://download.copr.fedorainfracloud.org/results/jdanek/skupper-router/srpm-builds/04126008/builder-live.log.gz)

On my machine, running `rpkg srpm` succeeds.

I searched around and it seems to me that COPR should be willing to download sources if they are distributed over https, which mine are.

Can I use the lookaside cache feature, somehow, for my sources?

Comment: I reported the problem at https://pagure.io/rpkg-util/issue/44

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, downloading the qpid-proton file by https would work in Copr. It's done by rpmbuild (being invoked by rpkg) if there is `%_disable_source_fetch 0` defined in rpm macros somewhere.

The problem is that one of the lines in the [spec file](https://github.com/jiridanek/skupper-router/blob/c4e28b63ddfc950c1fe34a37bf38daf25f628b70/skupper-router.spec.rpkg) is: `%undefine _disable_source_fetch` which disables this behavior for the given spec file.

Answer (score 1):

Your build fails on the `git_dir_pack` (rpkg-util, aka `rpkg` failure).  This happened before the `rpmbuild` process even started.

[A few weeks ago](https://lists.fedoraproject.org/archives/list/copr-devel@lists.fedorahosted.org/message/3JORYRKDWFMJSR35Z4LIKDEXH2T5263H/) we migrated the Copr builders to Fedora 35,
and thus also to rpkg-util `v3`.  Feel free to take a look [how
to fix similar issues](https://docs.pagure.org/copr.copr/rpkg_util_2_vs_3.html#rpkg-util-v3).
Or perhaps contact the [rpkg-util upstream](https://pagure.io/rpkg-util/issues) for a guidance.

Comment: That's not it, the `skupper-router-cb2a2900.tar.gz` was written correctly. `qpid-proton-0.37.0.tar.gz` is what failed, and that is not created by rpkg, that is downloaded from the URL that I give in the spec

Comment: Actually, it probably is it: "Auto-packing [...] When invoking rpkg srpm on an unpacked content, rpkg will download external sources (if any)" (https://pagure.io/fork/tmz/rpkg-util)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the sources file apparently *must* be downloaded from the lookaside cache. So, let's create ourselves one. Or at least, the *appearance* of one.

First, download the required source archive to your computer, to the git repo checkout dir, and do an "offline upload" using rpkg

```
wget https://www.apache.org/dist/qpid/proton/0.37.0/qpid-proton-0.37.0.tar.gz
rpkg upload --offline qpid-proton-0.37.0.tar.gz
```

This creates `sources` file. Commit that to the repo. Undo the edit to `.gitignore` that this also did. (If that rpkg command fails, ignore that as long as the `sources` file got created.)

Create new file `rpkg.conf` with the following content, and commit it to repo.

```
[lookaside]
download_url = https://www.apache.org/dist/qpid/proton/0.37.0/%(filename)s
```

Now push that and build it in COPR.

(Don't get confused by the obviously wrong `download_url` printed below; our `rpkg.conf` in the repo directory is overriding that.)

```
Running: git checkout jd_2022_03_15_rpm_cstdint

cmd: ['git', 'checkout', 'jd_2022_03_15_rpm_cstdint']
cwd: /var/lib/copr-rpmbuild/workspace/workdir-rmzys1po/skupper-router
rc: 0
stdout: branch 'jd_2022_03_15_rpm_cstdint' set up to track 'origin/jd_2022_03_15_rpm_cstdint'.
stderr: Switched to a new branch 'jd_2022_03_15_rpm_cstdint'

Generated rpkg config:
[rpkg]
preprocess_spec = True

[git]
anon_clone_url = https://github.com/%(repo_path)s

[lookaside]
download_url = https://${git_props:remote_netloc}/repo/pkgs/%(repo_path)s/%(filename)s/%(hashtype)s/%(hash)s/%(filename)s

Writing config into /var/lib/copr-rpmbuild/workspace/workdir-rmzys1po/.config/rpkg.conf
Running: rpkg srpm --outdir /var/lib/copr-rpmbuild/results --spec /var/lib/copr-rpmbuild/workspace/workdir-rmzys1po/skupper-router

cmd: ['rpkg', 'srpm', '--outdir', '/var/lib/copr-rpmbuild/results', '--spec', '/var/lib/copr-rpmbuild/workspace/workdir-rmzys1po/skupper-router']
cwd: /var/lib/copr-rpmbuild/workspace/workdir-rmzys1po/skupper-router
rc: 0
stdout: Downloading qpid-proton-0.37.0.tar.gz from jiridanek/skupper-router at www.apache.org:

Wrote: /var/lib/copr-rpmbuild/results/skupper-router.spec
Wrote: /var/lib/copr-rpmbuild/results/skupper-router-0.0.git.3560.d7714b9c-2.0.0.fc35.src.rpm
stderr: git_dir_pack: archiving /var/lib/copr-rpmbuild/workspace/workdir-rmzys1po/skupper-router:
commit d7714b9cac0641d4e34c0774b875fcb67cee8793 (HEAD -> jd_2022_03_15_rpm_cstdint, origin/jd_2022_03_15_rpm_cstdint)
Author: Jiri DanÄ›k <jdanek@redhat.com>
Date:   Wed Apr 13 17:13:22 2022 +0200

    add autopack
git_dir_pack: Wrote: /var/lib/copr-rpmbuild/results/skupper-router-d7714b9c.tar.gz

Output: ['skupper-router.spec', 'qpid-proton-0.37.0.tar.gz', 'skupper-router-0.0.git.3560.d7714b9c-2.0.0.fc35.src.rpm', 'skupper-router-d7714b9c.tar.gz']
```

Success!